# Simplfying an expression with exponentiation

Tags: calculus

$$u={\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}$$

This might be a trivial queston, but I seem to be stuck on out, or confused. I need help isolating for $$e^x$$

So how I see it we get rid of the square root first, so

$$u^2={{e^{2x}-1}}$$
Then we move the 1 over
$$u^2+1={{e^{2x}}}$$
Now i'm stuck, how do I get rid of the 2x? Is there an exponential property for this? Like if it was $$x^2$$ I know to just square root both sides

Comment: Note that $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$

Comment: So that mean I can also visualize it as e^2 multiplied by e^x

Comment: Not exactly. $e^2\cdot e^x=e^{2+x}$.

Comment: Ahh now I understand, I got the properties confused, thank you very much.

Comment: Exponent laws say $x^a\cdot x^b=x^{a+b}$ and $x^{ab}=(x^a)^b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

> $$e^{2x} = (e^x)^2 $$

$$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $$

Answer (score 0):

So you're at $$u^2 + 1 = e^{2x}$$

As said by another answer, first square root, since the $2$ in $e^{2x}$ counts a a square.

Then you have $$ \sqrt{u^2 + 1} = e^x$$

Use the natural log to isolate x

$$\ln(\sqrt{u^2 + 1}) = x\ln(e)$$
$$\ln(\sqrt{u^2 + 1}) = x $$

Answer (score 0):

$$u=\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}$$
$$u^2=e^{2x}-1$$
$$u^2+1=e^{2x}$$
Now note that:
$$\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$$
and so:
$$e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$$
you could also think of this as:
$$e^{2x}=e^{x+x}=e^xe^x=(e^x)^2$$
now you can finish off the problem by saying:
$$e^x=\sqrt{u^2+1}$$
if it is $x$ you want then it can be said that:
$$x=\ln\sqrt{u^2+1}=\frac12\ln(u^2+1)$$